# MyBatis log4j configuration to log only SQL names from mapper XMLs and not SQLs

Tags: java, logging, log4j, mybatis

When I set the following property in `log4j.properties`,

`log4j.logger.package.mapper=DEBUG`

MyBatis will delegate the job to `log4j`and `log4j` will print the WHOLE `SQL` statements in the log.
Is there a way to just log the names of the `SQL` statements (`id` in XML which matches the mapper function name in `JAVA` if done with annotations)?

Ex. my select query in mapper is like this, if done through `XML`:

```
<select id="selectPerson" parameterType="int" ....
```

then I just want `selectPerson` to be logged. Currently it is being logged but it also includes the `SQL` statemenets with all parameter values. I just want to hide the actual `SQL` queries from the log.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MyBatis' logging implementation does not have an option to hide SQL, however, it would be possible to achieve it using a custom [interceptor](https://mybatis.org/mybatis-3/configuration.html#plugins).
Assuming you are using the latest version of MyBatis, here is an example implementation.

```java
package pkg;

import org.apache.ibatis.executor.Executor;
import org.apache.ibatis.mapping.MappedStatement;
import org.apache.ibatis.plugin.Interceptor;
import org.apache.ibatis.plugin.Intercepts;
import org.apache.ibatis.plugin.Invocation;
import org.apache.ibatis.plugin.Signature;
import org.apache.ibatis.session.ResultHandler;
import org.apache.ibatis.session.RowBounds;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

@Intercepts({
  @Signature(
      type = Executor.class, 
      method = "update", 
      args = { MappedStatement.class, Object.class }),
  @Signature(
      type = Executor.class, 
      method = "query", 
      args = { MappedStatement.class, Object.class,
        RowBounds.class, ResultHandler.class })
})
public class LogStatementIdInterceptor implements Interceptor {
  private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(LogStatementInterceptor.class);
  @Override
  public Object intercept(Invocation invocation) throws Throwable {
    MappedStatement ms = (MappedStatement) invocation.getArgs()[0];
    logger.debug(ms.getId());
    return invocation.proceed();
  }
}
```

To register the interceptor, add the following entry to the XML config file.

```xml
<plugins>
  <plugin interceptor="pkg.LogStatementIdInterceptor" />
</plugins>
```

With Java config, pass an instance of the interceptor to `org.apache.ibatis.session.Configuration#addInterceptor()`.

And in the `log4j.properties` ...

```
log4j.logger.pkg.LogStatementIdInterceptor=DEBUG
```