# Is it possible of logging of Mybatis without SQL parameters?

Tags: logging, mybatis, spring-mybatis

I'm running a hobby Java Spring Mybatis project.

For development needs, the Mybatis logging always print SQL parameters along with the SQL statement.

Some parameters are rather long, that fill all my console screen and log files.

So I want to remove the parameters print, only display the SQL statement being executed.

After searches, not found an article explaining that yet.

Comment: MyBatis does not have such option. If you just want to know the statement ID, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59088102/1261766). If you want to see the SQL with placeholders (i.e. `?`), it probably is possible with [p6spy](https://github.com/p6spy/p6spy) with some customization. There could be a similar external JDBC logging tool that supports it out-of-the-box, but it's a very unusual requirement, I think.